# Diferença entre Arrays

Tags: javascript

Estou com uma duvida em um código:

Tenho estes dois arrays:

```
var listaLeituras= [12,13,14,15,16,17,18];<br>
var leiturasRealizadas = [12,15,18];
```

No final, eu precisava de um código para mostrar em um terceiro array as leituras não realizadas, que seriam os numeros 13,14,16,17. 
Tentei o código abaixo, porem,sem sucesso:

```
var leiturasIgnoradas = listaLeituras.filter(function(leitura) {<br>
  return leiturasRealizadas.indexOf(leitura) < 0;<br>
});
```

OBS: minha aplicação baseia-se no Javascript puro, não podendo usar bibliotecas externas.

Comment: O teu código está certo... (https://jsfiddle.net/9kjz7b16/) qual é o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode usar o [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains):

```
listaLeituras.filter(x => !leiturasRealizadas.includes(x));
```

EDIT:

Conforme mencionado pelo [Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss), o `includes` é experimental para o `ES7` e pode ser passível de mudanças. Recomenda-se olhar a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains) para consultar sua compatibilidade.

Comment: Vale lembrar que o `includes` ainda é experimental e não é indicado utilizar em produção. A solução alternativa seria `leiturasRealizadas.indexOf(x) < 0`

Comment: Obrigado pela observação. Editei minha resposta para adicionar esse ponto

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```js
var listaLeituras= [12,13,14,15,16,17,18];
var leiturasRealizadas = [12,15,18];

var leiturasIgnoradas = listaLeituras.filter(function(item) {
    return !~$.inArray(item, leiturasRealizadas);
});

console.log(leiturasIgnoradas);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`!~` É um atalho para ver se um valor é igual a -1 e se $.inArray(item, leiturasRealizadas) retornar -1, você sabe que o valor na matriz original não está na matriz de exclusão, então você mantê-lo.